# Get month wise count in MongoDB/Java Springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, aggregation

I have a collection in mongodb with below data:

**collection name: runState**

```
runId: 1
startTime:2020-09-16T20:56:06.598+00:00
endTime:2020-09-16T20:57:09.196+00:00
product_action: org_rhel_oracle_install
Task: completed
ranBy:David

runId: 2
startTime:2021-01-11T20:56:06.598+00:00
endTime:2021-01-11T20:56:09.196+00:00
product_action: org_rhel_oracle_install
Task: completed
ranBy:John

runId: 2
startTime:2021-01-27T20:56:06.598+00:00
endTime:2021-01-27T20:56:09.196+00:00
product_action: org_rhel_oracle_install
Task: completed
ranBy:John

runId: 3
startTime:2021-01-11T20:56:06.598+00:00
endTime:2021-01-11T20:57:09.196+00:00
product_action: org_rhel_postgres_install
Task: completed
ranBy:John

runId: 4
startTime:2021-02-09T20:56:06.598+00:00
endTime:2021-02-09T20:57:09.196+00:00
product_action: org_rhel_oracle_install
Task: completed
ranBy:John

runId: 5
startTime:2021-02-09T20:56:06.598+00:00
endTime:2021-02-09T20:57:09.196+00:00
product_action: org_rhel_postgres_install
Task: completed
ranBy:John

runId: 6
startTime:2021-09-09T20:56:06.598+00:00
endTime:2021-09-09T20:57:09.196+00:00
product_action: org_rhel_postgres_install
Task: completed
ranBy:John

runId: 7
startTime:2022-01-09T20:56:06.598+00:00
endTime:2022-01-09T20:57:09.196+00:00
product_action: org_rhel_oracle_install
Task: completed
ranBy:David

runId: 8
startTime:2022-01-10T20:56:06.598+00:00
endTime:2022-01-10T20:57:09.196+00:00
product_action: org_rhel_oracle_install
Task: failed
ranBy:David
```

I want the output as count for last 12 months (Jan 2021 to Jan 2022) for each products where task is completed( product is gettable from product_action)

Output should be in below format:

```
{
"_id" : "postgres",
completed: [
        {
            "month" : "FEB-2021",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "month" : "SEP-2021",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "month" : "JAN-2021",
            "count" : 1
        }
]
},
{
"_id" : "oracle",
    "completed" : [
        {
            "month" : "FEB-2021",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "month" : "JAN-2021",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I have started with below, but not sure how to get count for month wise like above.

```
{"product_action":{$regex:"postgres|oracle"},"Task":"completed"}
```

**As this is new to me, can someone help me with mongo DB query to get the result and also code to acheive this in Java springboot?**

Java code I tried using aggregation, but this is not yielding the result I want.

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.project("endTime","Task","product_action").and(DateOperators.Month.monthOf("endTime")).as("month"),
                Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("product_action").regex("postgres|oracle").and("Task").is("completed")
                        .and("endTime").gte(parseDate("2021-02-01"))),
                Aggregation.group("month","Task").count().as("count")
                );
```

Comment: Are those start and end times real MongoDB datetimes or are they strings?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti those are real mongoDB datetimes and not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // Get easy stuff out way. Filter for the desired date range and only
    // those items that are complete:
    {$match: {$and: [
        {"endTime":{$gte:new ISODate("2021-01-01")}},
        {"endTime":{$lt:new ISODate("2022-01-01")}},
        {"Task":"completed"}
    ]} }

    // Now group by product and date expressed as month-year.  The product
    // is embedded in the field value so there are a few approaches to digging
    // it out.  Here, we split on underscore and take the [2] item.
    ,{$group: {_id: {
        p: {$arrayElemAt:[{$split:["$product_action","_"]},2]},
        d: {$dateToString: {date: "$endTime", format: "%m-%Y"}}
               },
               n: {$sum: 1}
    }}

    // The OP seeks to make the date component nested inside the product
    // instead of having it as a two-part grouping.  We will "regroup" and
    // create an array.  This is slightly different than the format indicated
    // by the OP but values as keys (e.g. "Jan-2021: 2") is in general a 
    // poor idea so instead we construct an array of proper name:value pairs.
    ,{$group: {_id: '$_id.p',
               completed: {$push: {d: '$_id.d', n: '$n'}}
    }}

]);
```

which yields

```js
{
    "_id" : "postgres",
    "completed" : [
        {
            "d" : "02-2021",
            "n" : 1
        },
        {
            "d" : "09-2021",
            "n" : 1
        },
        {
            "d" : "01-2021",
            "n" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "oracle",
    "completed" : [
        {
            "d" : "02-2021",
            "n" : 1
        },
        {
            "d" : "01-2021",
            "n" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATED**

It has come up before that the `$dateToString` function does not have a format argument to produce the 3 letter abbreviation for a month e.g. `JAN` (or a long form e.g. `January` for that matter).  Sorting still works with `01-2021,02-2021,04-2021` vs. `JAN-2021,FEB-2021,APR-2021` but if such output is really desired directly from the DB instead of post-processing in the client-side code, then the second group is replaced by a `$sort` and `$group` as follows:

```js
    // Ensure the NN-YYYY dates are going in increasing order.  The product
    // component _id.p does not matter here -- only the dates have to be
    // increasing.  NOTE:  This is OPTIONAL with respect to changing
    // NN-YYYY into MON-YYYY but almost always the follow on question is
    // how to get the completed list in date order...
    ,{$sort: {'_id.d':1}}

    // Regroup as before but index the NN part of NN-YYYY into an
    // array of 3 letter abbrevs, then reconstruct the string with the
    // dash and the year component.  Remember: the order of the _id 
    // in the doc stream coming out of $group is not deterministic
    // but the array created by $push will preserve the order in
    // which it was pushed -- which is the date-ascending sorted order
    // from the prior stage.
    ,{$group: {_id: '$_id.p',
               completed: {$push: {
                   d: {$concat: [
                       {$arrayElemAt:[ ['JAN','FEB','MAR',
                                        'APR','MAY','JUN',
                                        'JUL','AUG','SEP',
                                        'OCT','NOV','DEC'],
                       // minus 1 to adjust for zero-based array:
                       {$subtract:[{$toInt: {$substr:['$_id.d',0,2]}},1]}
                             ]},
                       "-",
                       {$substr:['$_id.d',3,4]}
                   ]},
                   n: '$n'}}
              }}
```

which yields:

```js
{
    "_id" : "postgres",
    "completed" : [
        {
            "d" : "JAN-2021",
            "n" : 1
        },
        {
            "d" : "FEB-2021",
            "n" : 1
        },
        {
            "d" : "SEP-2021",
            "n" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "oracle",
    "completed" : [
        {
            "d" : "JAN-2021",
            "n" : 2
        },
        {
            "d" : "FEB-2021",
            "n" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

As for converting this to Java, there are several approaches but unless a great deal of programmatic control is required, then capturing the query as "relaxed JSON" (quotes not required around keys) in a string in Java and calling `Document.parse()` seems to be the easiest way.  A full example including helper functions and the appropriate Java drivers calls can be found here: https://moschetti.org/rants/mongoaggcvt.html  but the gist of it is:

```java
    private static class StageHelper {
        private StringBuilder txt;

        public StageHelper() {
            this.txt = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public void add(String expr, Object ... subs) {
            expr.replace("'", "\""); // This is the helpful part.                            
            if(subs.length > 0) {
                expr = String.format(expr, subs);  // this too                               
            }
            txt.append(expr);
        }
        public Document fetch() {
            Document b = Document.parse(txt.toString());
            return b;
        }
    }

    private List<Document> makePipeline() {
        List<Document> pipeline = new ArrayList<Document>();

        StageHelper s = new StageHelper();
        s.add("{$match: {$and: [ ");

        // Note use of EJSON here plus string substitution of dates:                         
        s.add("  {endTime:{$gte: {$date: '%s'}} }", "2021-01-01");
        s.add("  {endTime:{$lt: {$date: '%s'}} }", "2022-01-01");

        s.add("  {Task:'completed'} ");
        s.add("]} } ");
        pipeline.add(s.fetch());

        s = new StageHelper();
        s.add("{$group: {_id: { ");
        s.add("  p: {$arrayElemAt:[{$split:['$product_action','_']},2]}, ");
        s.add("  d: {$dateToString: {date: '$endTime', 'format': '%m-%Y'}} ");
        s.add("  }, ");
        s.add("  n: {$sum: 1}  ");
        s.add("}} ");
        pipeline.add(s.fetch());

        s = new StageHelper();
        s.add("{$sort: {'_id.d':1}} ");
        pipeline.add(s.fetch());

        s = new StageHelper();
        s.add("{$group: {_id: '$_id.p', ");
        s.add("        completed: {$push: { ");
        s.add("            d: {$concat: [ ");
        s.add("                {$arrayElemAt:[ ['JAN','FEB','MAR', ");
        s.add("                                 'APR','MAY','JUN', ");
        s.add("                                 'JUL','AUG','SEP', ");
        s.add("                                 'OCT','NOV','DEC'], ");
        s.add("                {$subtract:[{$toInt: {$substr:['$_id.d',0,2]}},1]} ");
        s.add("                      ]}, ");
        s.add("                '-', ");
        s.add("                {$substr:['$_id.d',3,4]} ");
        s.add("            ]}, ");
        s.add("            n: '$n'}} ");
        s.add("       }} ");
        pipeline.add(s.fetch());

    return pipeline;
    }
...
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
    import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable;

    AggregateIterable<Document> output = coll.aggregate(pipeline);
    MongoCursor<Document> iterator = output.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Document doc = iterator.next();
```

Comment: thanks for this. I am trying to do the java code using aggregation. Updated my question with the code i have tried, can you please check that and help?

Comment: I have updated the question with the java code I am trying, It would be great if you can modify that and share.

Comment: Are you using Java 13 or higher?   Basically, with support for text blocks (triple quotes)?

Comment: I am using Java 1.8

Comment: I do not know what Java driver rev you are using.   I use 4.3.2 and it has no `Aggregation` class so no `Aggregation.newAggregation` method.  If that is a springboot thing then I am afraid I cannot help.

Comment: no issues, if you can provide full code in Java with whatever you have written, will be good as it is not clear like the one which you provided with mongo query.

Comment: @Syed Answer updated with Java code that actually ran on my platform to produce the same results as the javascript.  Don't be shy about clicking both an upvote and the accepted answer flag.

Comment: why not!! :) Thanks for the code and the time you spent. I got the result that I want.